# Proving number of 0-1 sequences of length n that avoid 1111 equal to tetranacci (n+4)

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

The number of binary sequences of length n that avoid the appearance of 1111 is equal to the n+4th tetranacci number.

I can see the relation between the sequence and tetranacci number but where does the +4 factor come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have derived the relation: $$a_{n} = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4},$$
for $n\geq 4.$ Also, $a_0=T_3=1, a_1 = 2=T_4, a_2 = 4=T_5, a_3 = 8 = T_6.$ Hence, by induction, you can see that $a_n = T_{n+3}$.

I guess your problem says $T_{n+4}$ because it's using a slightly different definition of the Tetranacci numbers.

Comment: I can now see that the problem does give a different definition of the Tetranacci numbers to that which I am used to. 
I haven't derived the first equation, which is what I'm trying to do. Could you give any hints without giving away the answer please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can find your answer in the one  of  exercises of the valuable book [A first course in discrete mathematics by Ian Anderson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852332360). The exercise and hint for solution of it is as follows 
[image]